# Remainder of polynomial division using a graphical approach?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

Given a polynomial long division problem, is  it possible to find the remainder using purely a graph?

For example, let’s say we have a given trinomial $6x^2+7x+10$ and we divide this trinomial by the binomial $2x+5$.  Can we find the remainder by purely graphing the given trinomial and binomial (or some function derived from these two polynomials)?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Just graph both functions , look where $g(x)=2x+5$ becomes $0$ and look which value $f(x)=6x^2+7x+10$ has there. Of course this only works because the remainder is a real number. The degree of $g(x)$ must be $1$